# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error:- Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The PHP version is "PHP 7.4.30", MariaDB version (mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.8-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1). and I am using Centos 7.

When I run the file locally it works but when I run the same file on the browser it shows the 500 error https://passimage.in/i/9fd1937c0a5d389b447e.png and in error_log I see "PHP Fatal error"
Here is the example code

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','my_user','my_password','my_db', 'port', '/path/mysql/mysql.sock');
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.")". $mysqli->connect_error;
  exit();
}
else {
  echo "connected";
}
```

The error i see is

```
[Mon Aug 08 08:07:54.188110 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 21030] [client 59.92.251.25:56390] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/deep/public_html/wpinfo.php:15\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /home/deep/public_html/wpinfo.php on line 15\n'
```

In /etc/php.ini i have uncommented `extension=mysqli`

the mysqli is installed https://passimage.in/i/c9a19a98cdc1627f2420.png, but the default port and path are different. but in my `/etc/my.cnf` file the port and socket path is set. In the Database, I can see the port is set https://passimage.in/i/c994d99f4fc812c6a0ca.png.
Is it causing the issue? if yes how to change it?

any help would be appreciated
thank you!

Comment: Change the first parameter to add the port: `mysqli_connect('localhost:3307',...`

Comment: Display All PHP Errors then tail the server using this command as you open the page *tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log* . A more verbose error message could be displayed and possibly give direction

Comment: Make sure you edit the correct `php.ini` for your webserver (run a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to get the path). Restart your webserver after enabling PHP extensions

Comment: @PaulT. How will that help if the function isn't even defined?

Comment: Please edit your question and show [**the error logs you have read**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel)

Comment: @Barmar ... well, I guess I only covered 1/2 the picture. I should have asked about restarting the webserver too, at least.

Comment: @PaulT. wouldn't it be better to update the `php.ini` settings with the correct port? 3306 is the default, 3307 is not.

Comment: @Martin ... sure, but I don't know what install set 3307.

Comment: @Martin: i have updated the error logs

Comment: @PaulT. i have added the port `mysqli_connect('localhost:3307',...`  but i still face the same error on browser